# Why newest HID usage table does not contain "Contact identifier (page 0x0D, usage 0x51)"

Tags: usb, hid

Here is the newest HID usage table spec:
http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf

But I cannot find out the usage ID: 0x51 from usage page 0x0d?
and this usage has already mentioned in microsoft?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/supporting-usages-in-multitouch-digitizer-drivers

Comment: What is the problem you have? What is your question? How is this related to programming? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also recommend [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

It's described in HID Usage Tables Review Request 34 on the [HID Tools page](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage) at usb.org.

Download it from [Review Request 34:  Multi-touch digitizers](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HUTRR34.zip)